# How to convert 10,00,000 from 1,000,000 in SQL oracle or (convert million to lac)?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need help from you? I want to convert million format in lac in oracle.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a `varchar2` in one format to a `varchar2` in another format?  How to convert a `number` to a `varchar2` in a particular format?  Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use TO_CHAR with a suitable format string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1000000,'FM99G99G99G999') FROM DUAL;

10,00,000
```

Comment: Indeed, that's what `TO_CHAR` does.